# \curvearrowright above a letter, like \overrightarrow, but curved

Tags: math-mode, arrows

So I want to use a curved arrow above a letter, that looks something like this:
[image: this]

How do I achieve this? I want to use this symbol in normal math mode, so it shouldn't preferably mess up formatting around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is sufficient. (Note, however, that you need extra efforts if you want to use it in section titles and use `hyperref`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\curvearrowright}{\mathcal{O}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not sure if I'd go for that but you can scale things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\curvearrowright}{\mathcal{O}}$ $\accentset{\scalebox{1}[0.6]{$\curvearrowright$}}{\mathcal{O}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can go for a much more complicated solution, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,bending,calc}
\newcounter{coverarcarrow}
\newcommand{\overarcarrow}[2][]{\stepcounter{coverarcarrow}%
\overset{\vphantom{+}}{\tikzmarknode{coverarcarrow-\number\value{coverarcarrow}}{#2}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw let \p1=($(coverarcarrow-\number\value{coverarcarrow}.north east)-(coverarcarrow-\number\value{coverarcarrow}.south west)$),
 \n1={atan2(2ex,\x1)} in 
 [-{Stealth[bend,length={min(0.3*\x1,0.8ex)}]},semithick,#1]
 ([yshift=0.2*\y1]coverarcarrow-\number\value{coverarcarrow}.north west) 
 to[out=\n1,in=180] ([yshift=0.8ex]coverarcarrow-\number\value{coverarcarrow}.north)
 to[out=0,in={180-\n1}] ([yshift=0.2*\y1]coverarcarrow-\number\value{coverarcarrow}.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$\overarcarrow{\mathcal{O}}$ 
$\overarcarrow{\mathcal{O}_1\mathcal{O}_2\cdots\mathcal{O}_n}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is (almost) perfect! Is there any way to make the arrow slightly larger? I tried adding a \large in the definition, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @taninamdar I added some more variants but I am not convinced by either of them,

Comment: Thanks, the first variant is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `fourier` package it is possible to see the symbol `\wideOarc{...}`. I have added `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathccal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` to have the calligraphic symbols of computer modern (CM):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathccal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
$\wideOarc{\mathccal{O}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]